# Is there a quick way to check a server for Craft's minimum requirements?

Tags: php, requirements

Is there a quick way (or some sort of wizard) that can be run on a server in order to establish whether it fulfils Craft's minimum requirements without uploading all of the Craft files? Finding out PHP and MySQL versions is easy enough but sometimes it's hard to get the finer details from clients.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no way of programmatically checking whether a server fulfils the minimum requirements in Craft without uploading all of the Craft files, however I have created a script that performs all of Craft's web server related checks. It does not connect to a database so cannot check the MySQL version or that the InnoDB storage engine is installed and enabled, but this should be relatively easy to find out by asking your web hosting company.

The script is available for download here:

https://github.com/putyourlightson/craft-requirements

Comment: Hey Ben. To fully answer your question, you may want to elaborate on, or at least give a little more context as to where to look, regarding MySQL and InnoDB.  Saying 'this should be relatively easy to find out' is usually not the case for folks who are unfamiliar with these technologies.

Comment: good point ben, i've updated the explanation slightly and plan on adding this functionality to my script soon.