# Does Craft have an installer error log I can check?

Tags: install, error-message

I've tried to install Craft on a variety of systems, and it seems that no matter what I try, I cannot get all the way through the installation process. In most cases, my install hangs on the "Oops" screen.

[image]

I've learned not to trust this screen, because if I immediately close the window and cancel my installation, the installer screen continues to show up when trying to access the admin login /admin/.

Instead, if I just let it sit for a few minutes then close the screen, it seems like the install actually works as expected. Visiting /admin/ in my browser has the desired affect, and I'm able to use the CMS as expected.

My thought is that it might be something related to the install cleanup process - but I'd like to take a peek at the install log file to see exactly where things went wrong.

I've checked system requirements, although on some systems, I'm unable to personally verify all of the requirements are met. But I'd like to know why I got that "Oops" screen. It's obviously a non-critical error, or else the db and system would not function properly - which it does.

Answer (score 7):

Typically the Craft logs are stored here:

```
/craft/storage/runtime/logs
```

I don't know how much logging the installer does, but if it does any at all, that's where you'll find the log data.

In the meantime, you can also try this [script by Ben Croker](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/138/45) which will check your server configuration to make sure it has everything it needs to proceed.

Answer (score 4):

All of Craft's log files get stored in `craft/storage/runtime/logs`.

If you're running in [devMode](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#devMode), then any log message with a `trace`, `info`, `warning` or `error` severity error will get logged there in addition to lots of database profiling information.

If `devMode` is off, only `warning` and `error` get logged.

Installation is a special exception to this config setting.  During installation, Craft will run with `devMode` on, regardless of what it is set to in the config file precisely to help debug installation issues.

Craft will run it's requirements checker and block the installation letting you know what's missing if a requirement is not met.  [Ben's script](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/138/45) is handy if you want to check your server's requirements *before* uploading Craft's file.

Also worth noting that PHP's error logs also get redirected to the same folder and that Craft will keep 6MB of log files before it starts to rotate the oldest logs out.

If you can't figure out the cause of the issue, be sure and hit us up at support@buildwithcraft.com and we'll take stab at it, too.