# Craft install stuck on "Oops" screen

Tags: database, install

I've uploaded the files, verified permissions and set up the database. When I run the install, I see the monkey, and I enter in my details. It appears to go well, until a screen showing only: "**Oops**"

Using [Ben Croker's Craft Requirements Checker](https://github.com/putyourlightson/craft-requirements), I get:

> **Success**
>
> Minimum requirements met. Craft can run on this server!!

The server is running **MySQL 5.1.56** with **InnoDB**, so I believe it's capable of running Craft.

Any advice?

Comment: @JimKrenz If you want to shoot some FTP/database credentials over to support@buildwithcraft.com, we can look at it and update the thread here with the results.

Comment: @BradBell — Sent. Thanks for taking a look at it!

Comment: Did you sort this, I'm getting the same error over and over again..

Comment: I'm also getting this on a local Windows install of **Craft 3** running WAMP. Don't have time to troubleshoot it right now, but will try post back if I figure it out.

Comment: This question is very closely related to [Does Craft have an installer error log I can check?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1279/does-craft-have-an-installer-error-log-i-can-check)

Answer (score 5):

The cause of this is most likely an overloaded (very common if this is a shared hosting account) or misconfigured MySQL server.

The installer itself should only take 10-20 seconds on 99% of hosts.  However on this one, it sits for about 120 seconds, before Apache redirects the AJAX request to:

```
'p' => 'internal_error.html',
```

As seen from your log files.  The underlying error is probably being logged in your Apache error logs, but it is most likely something related to a timeout from the long request.

If I try to manually execute the SQL from a database dump that is working, removing Craft from the equation entirely, it does finish in time, but still takes about 45 seconds when it should be done in less than 10.

I'd contact your host and ask them to check on the performance/configuration of your MySQL box.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back Brad! Is it possible to provide information like this on the "Oops" screen? As it stands now, "Oops" isn't very helpful. :)

Comment: The problem with PHP and fatal errors like this is there isn't a graceful way to recover, much less get any information about the underlying error from PHP. They aren't normal exceptions that can be caught and dealt with in a try/catch block.

Comment: Fair enough, that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I am troubleshooting this with the host, as they are claiming that there aren't any issues with the server that is hosting my database. So, I am not considering this answered as of the moment.

Comment: Of course they are. :)  Which host is it?

Comment: Dreamhost. To their credit, their servers run WordPress very well, and even Drupal adequately (and Drupal throws its weight at the database servers a lot).

Comment: To reach closure on this: I decided to move on in my research—at this point, I need software that works gracefully on shared hosting. 

The MySQL servers in question aren't overloaded or misconfigured in my experience. They have handled other software installations well—Craft is the only one to date that failed during the installation. My brief experience Craft on my local server didn't inspire me to pursue it further. I'll check in on Craft again in the future, to see its progress. Best of luck with it!