# oops screen on Mamp Pro install

Tags: mamp

Hi got past the username etc screen for install but stuck on the 'oops' screen?
I've tried again and again but same deal, checked db settings just not getting past this, assuming the oops means it can't connect to the db but if the details are correct (I have a pw with its own un and pw with privs for that) and tested with root root, any ideas – seems most people are having no probs with this, then tried logging in and ok, why would it hang do you think on oops when seems to have installed?

Comment: If you drop the database entirely and create a new one, does that help?

Comment: Thanks Marion, not yet, after several installs, still can't source the issue

Comment: This question seems to overlap a lot with [Does Craft have an installer error log I can check?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1279/does-craft-have-an-installer-error-log-i-can-check)

Answer (score 1):

If Craft can't connect to the database, it will let you know.  Some other error is occurring. Check your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files for an `[error]` entry, and that will have the error message that is occurring.

Also, in between installation attempts, be sure to delete any tables that were created in the database from a previous install attempt.

Comment: Although I can now see the error log, I'm not certain what the error is  ---- [warning] [application] Skipping record /Users/Mymac/Sites/ontherocks/craft/app/records/BaseRecord.php because it’s abstract or an interface.  I went to /admin ad logged in ok, added fields etc and okay, worried my Mamp settings are wrong although seems ok for other system installs

Comment: That one isn't causing the problem.  Are there no `[error]` entries being logged?

Comment: 2015/01/17 07:26:15 [error] [exception.Craft\HttpException.404] exception 'Craft\HttpException' in /Users/Mac/Sites/craft-demo/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php:737
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/Mac/Sites/craft-demo/craft/app/etc/web/WebApp.php(176): Craft\WebApp->_processInstallRequest()
#1 /Users/Mac/Sites/craft-demo/craft/app/framework/base/CApplication.php(180): Craft\WebApp->processRequest()
#2 /Users/Mac/Sites/craft-demo/craft/app/index.php(62): CApplication->run()
#3 /Users/Mac/Sites/craft-demo/public/index.php(19): require_once('/Users/Mac/Site...')
#4 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/
---
any ideas?

Comment: Sorry... that's just a 404. Any `[error]` other than a `HttpException.404`?

Comment: [info] [application] [Forced] Trying to write to file at /Users/Mac/Sites/craft-demo/craft/storage/runtime/cache/06d99ef33038f0014d8f3ce02e7e5d5e.bin using LOCK_EX.
in /Users/Mac/Sites/craft-demo/craft/app/helpers/IOHelper.php (786)
2015/01/19 23:44:03 [info] [application] [Forced] Successfully wrote to file at /Users/Mac/Sites/craft-demo/craft/storage/runtime/cache/06d99ef33038f0014d8f3ce02e7e5d5e.bin using LOCK_EX. Saving in cache.
in /Users/Mac/Sites/craft-demo/craft/app/helpers/IOHelper.php (793)

Comment: Right... but those aren't errors.  If you want to zip up your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` folder and send it to support@buildwithcraft.com, we can look through them and I'll update with the answer here.

Comment: I tried again on Mamp Pro – deleted the tables and reinstalled – and still get the Oops screen – will send logs to you if ok?

Comment: Sure thing, @KevN.

Comment: Any resolution to this issue. I am having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after struggling for hours I found out that I had to stop MySQL server from running in System Preferences. After that the insallation was successful