# Craft Installation Next Button Not doing anything

Tags: installation

I am in the first step of the installation. I entered my email, username and password and clicked on the next button, but it is not doing anything.

It makes a post request to:
/var/www/html/test_craft/craft/app/index.php

And a Get request to:
http://localhost/public/index.php?p=admin/resources/images/spinner_submit.gif&d=1465331044

Looks like the get request is not returning anything because in firebug, the response is a spinning wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Well, things should be going very smoothly from here, so there is pretty surely something not right with your installation.

1) did you make sure to rename the installed file public/htaccess to public/.htaccess? I'm not sure if this is critical to the installer, but it might be.

2) You can look in craft/storage/runtime/logs. There you find craft.log and phperrors.log. Either may hold information to help.

3) It sounds that your database login config is ok, as otherwise the Craft installer would notify about that, but you may not have all the other server requirements in place yet. See: https://craftcms.com/docs/requirements.

For requirements testing, see: [Is there a quick way to check a server for Craft's minimum requirements?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/137/is-there-a-quick-way-to-check-a-server-for-crafts-minimum-requirements)

4) Getting no response would be quite unusual. It's possible that your Craft installation is faulty -- FTP in general is often not entirely reliable. You could remove, then re-upload and replace the installation. If you do this and can, I'd suggest uploading the zip, then unzipping it on the server. Again, then, don't forget to rename the htaccess to .htaccess.

5) all this presumes you are running on Apache. If Nginx instead, here are two references that should help. I'd go with the first as that's from the Craft team based on what works for others. I use Nginx all the time, as do many others, and it's fine once configured:

[What is the recommended Nginx configuration for Craft?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/961/what-is-the-recommended-nginx-configuration-for-craft)

https://gist.github.com/kenzie/5811327

Good fortune then. Again, Craft installs are nearly as effortless as Craft updates, unless there is something wrong in the configuration or preparations.

Comment: It occurred to me this morning that when you say the install start button 'does nothing', this might be a variant on the usual result when PHP isn't configured to have enough memory, which would be a white screen. Thus I'd be sure to carefully look at the phperrors.log in step 2) above, as it would tell you. In that case, adjustment via php.ini or iby your hoster would be the way to fix that.